# Django: groupby with getting first row

Tags: mysql, django

I have table as

Model name: `Test`

```
id col1 col2 col3 col4 .....
1   A   1
2   A   1
3   A   3
4   B   1
5   B   1
6   B   4
7   D   2
8   D   3
9   D   3
10  F   3
11  B   4
```

I want to get all the rows with unique combination of col1 and col2 and the row with recent id and also the total count of the unique combination of col1 and col2

```
count   id col1 col2 col3 col4 .....
2       11  B   4
1       10  F   3
1       9   D   3
1       7   D   2
2       5   B   1
1       3   A   3
1       2   A   1
```

and also later i want to sort w.r.t count and id. But i want the above table also

```
count   id col1 col2 col3 col4 .....
2       11  B   4
2       5   B   1
1       10  F   3
1       9   D   3
1       7   D   2
1       3   A   3
1       2   A   1
```

How can i get this

I am using mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) as count,max(id) as id,col1,col2 FROM test group by col1,col2 order by id desc;
```

sort:

```
SELECT count(*) as count,max(id) as id,col1,col2 FROM test group by col1,col2 order by count desc,id desc;
```